# tcolorbox making all of my text move with it

Tags: tcolorbox

Apologies I am a total novice with latex, so sorry if this is a very stupid question.

I am using tcolorbox. It is moving all of the subsections above it onto the same page as itself, leaving a large gap on the previous page. I understand why it would move itself onto a new page so it is altogether, but why is it moving my previous subsections too? I even tried putting a 'fake' or blank subsection above it, so it thinks its in its own subsection and will stop messing with my other ones. But it didnt work.

Please help and great thanks!

[image]

I have the 
     \usepackage{tcolorbox}

```
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{\large What?}
 text 
 \subsection{\large How?} 
  text 
 \subsection{\large  }

 \begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=white]
 \textbf{Figure 1. Title}
  text
 \begin{center}  
 \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{basicscience}  
 \small{John Hopkins: Basic Science CFTR}
 \end{center}
  text 
 \end{tcolorbox}
```

Comment: If you place the tcolorbox in a `figure` environment, it will float.

Answer (score 4):

If you want that `tcolorbox` could break between pages, make it `breakable`. If you want your figures as `floats` but inside a `tcolorbox` declare them as `float`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=figures]{myfigure}[2][]{
    float, halign=center, title={#2}, #1}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{What?}
 \lipsum[1]
 \subsection{How?} 
 \lipsum[2]
 \subsection{Another}
 \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, colframe=white]
  \lipsum[3]
 \begin{center}  
 \includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{example-image}\\ 
 \small{John Hopkins: Basic Science CFTR}
 \end{center}
 \lipsum[1]
 \end{tcolorbox}

 \begin{myfigure}{This is figure's title}
 \includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{example-image}\\ 
 \small{John Hopkins: Basic Science CFTR}
  \end{myfigure}

 \end{document}
```

[image]